# Any method to improve performance when display fractional scaling used?

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I have connected 4k monitor with ubuntu laptop and I am getting 4k 30 FPS. If I run 4k without scaling its normal. But when I do fractional scaling, performance takes a hit. My cursor is very slow, same applies to any video played on youtube (Even playing Youtube videos in 1080p stutters). It looks like as if I am getting only 15 FPS and everything shown on monitor is affected.
Is there anything I can do to solve above problem ?

Answer (score 0):

in meantime I'm waiting that someone answer to my question I saw your post and jump into it!

I have the same Settings like you (4k external Monitor laptop), with "fractional scaling" it's a bit particular because with the 4K if you will change the DPI with Fractiona Scaling , everything it's correct but the PC will display the Resolution in 4k but in reality the output of the resolution it's 5120x2880 5k (if you use 150%) and it called "Panning" so your PC will output more power GPU because need to manage the fake 5k Resolution for keep the right DPI fractional scaling. Now, what I can suggest you , sometimes when you change the monitor setting the Hz will change as well, I suggest you to check again under the Ubuntu setting-Monitor if the Frequenzy under the Resolution section it's to **60Hz**

Comment: I checked, its 30 Hz. But even 30 Hz videos are stuttering and the cursor as well.

Comment: 30 Hz ofcourse it's stuttering..... So , cannot be changed to 60Hz? Do you have Nvidia Graphic Card?

Comment: My laptop is old, max it can do is 4k 30 Hz. I dont feel that much bad performance on disabling scaling.

Comment: If the laptop it's old I suggest you to take out the Fractional Scaling, and play only with 100% or 200% normal DPI and adjust the Icons and the Words system by the theme OS. Because now your laptop it's suffering like mad as it has to manage the 5K Resolution internally to Display you the right 4K DPI under The Fractional Scaling. It's Incredible but unfortunately it's the way how the Fractional Scaling it's working and if the GPU cannot hold such resolution , you will have many problems with managing of the Hz , whatch a simple video on YouTube and simple ordinary daily movements with the PC

Comment: yeah, I should have bought 32' monitor instead of 28' . How does 200 % scaling not affect performance ? And what is theme OS ?

Comment: For 4K would be better 32',  the 28' it's nice to have 2k Monitor. Anyway, it's not the problems of  the normal DPI functions like 100% - 200% - 300% - 400%, the problems comes when you select (and on 4k monito it's a must) the Fractional DPI Scaling, this mode to manage the intermediate scale between 100 and 200% use a "system around" to display better the proportion of the things, and to me it's really strange to see such way in 2021 OS. Probably because the Xorg that menage the DPI it's too old way for new system era, that can only allows the whole numbers to be set. 1 = 100%, 2 = 200%, etc

Comment: I forgot... if you have installed Gnome-Tweaks or you can go to System Settings and under Accessibility you can change there the Cursor with the Words to make more bigger. For the Icons you can set them under the voice "Appearence"...

Comment: I set font scaling factor to 1.5, idk if its right to increase that much without enabling system wide scaling. Btw I checked on windows 10, I tried every fractional scaling option, it was normal. So only ubuntu is behaving abnormal and does not look like laptop configuration is issue.

Comment: In Windows it's normal because it's well made about;  because the system always improve with the years, so for paradox, Windows has got many problems in past but in the same time helps to fix a billions things. Ubuntu (i think as per any Linux Distro) use the XORG to manage the Desktop Enviroment but it's a way in old style and fixed it in the years with a lot "Around Solutions" that arrived in our days it's a bit absolete, for this reason come out Wayland Solution , that should replace Xorg to manage all the Comunication Enviroment......-->

Comment: ....--> in the past (and even recently)  I have tested others Linux Distro, I didn't noticed about this problems till I have installed Ubuntu. So, as I know, should be any Linux that it has Xorg as Desktop Enviroment but why in other Distros like Debian base I didn't noticed it before I don't have the answer about....

Comment: So do you mean if I switch to Wayland then performance would improve ? I would try it.

Comment: Theoretically, yes, but I never tried with Ubuntu. For sure in Deepin OS (Debian base) and Zorin OS (Ubuntu base) I never had got this DPI problem. If with Wayland, still persist this silly DPI problem, in this case maybe Canonical need work on it because it's quite absurd this situation in our days.... Please, if you will try let me know, because I'm curious as well on it.

Comment: I could not succeed, but wait, 21.04 is here !